# Is this a function decorator?

Tags: python, syntax

I've just started playing around with pyglet.

In the [first demo](http://www.pyglet.org/doc/programming_guide/hello_world.html), I ran accross code like this:

```
window = pyglet.window.Window()

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    label.draw()
```

I understand that this registers an event handler, but I don't understand how.

How could this be rewritten without the '@' syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called an "event decorator." Yes, you could just write

window.on_draw = on_draw

after the "def on_draw()" definition, without using the decorator; but then if the window already had an on_draw, it would be overwritten. The decorator will "chain" multiple event handlers together.

Comment: More to the point, you could write `on_draw = window.event(on_draw)` to the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://www.pyglet.org/doc/api/pyglet.window.Window-class.html), `Window.event` is a decorator. Decorators can be simply added via using an `@`.